# Add a top bar to bottomNavigationView selected item

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

How to add a selection bar on bottom navigation selected item as shown below.
[image]

How to achieve this.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: check this link :-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325422/selected-tabs-color-in-bottom-navigation-view

Comment: @vinuZachariah this doesn't allow adding the top bar on `bottomNavigationView`

Comment: @vishnusatheesh check this link :- https://www.abdulazizahwan.com/2020/03/customizable-animated-bottom-bar.html

Comment: @Harshil the link shared is a library, any possibility of implementing the same without using libraries?

Comment: try this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69234461/how-to-change-the-bottom-navigation-indicator-width

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69234461/how-to-change-the-bottom-navigation-indicator-width